# css footer cutting in the sides

Tags: html, css, footer, margins

I am trying to make an infinite footer to the sides, and even though it's infinite, there is a small margin to the left and right of the footer. I don't have any margins set to my body, html, or anything, so I am unsure on what may be causing this.

Here is my footer css:

```
#footer {
    height: 72px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #174466;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And here is the html:

```
<div id="footer">

</div>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a reset stylesheet? What browser? Can you provide an image of what your issue is?

Comment: What do use to make footer, div or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't have any margins set to my
>   body, html

That either means you're *not setting* it at all, or that you're setting it to `0`.

I'm going to guess that you're not setting it at all, and so you need to zero out the *default* `margin`/`padding` on `body`/`html`.

Try adding this CSS, preferably at the top of your style sheet (for good organization):

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
```